# Cognito issued JWT does not contain user roles

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

According to this SO - [User roles in Amazon Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818906/393805) the user roles should be available in the JWT returned by Cognito. However when inspecting the JWT I don't see any roles nor the `cognito:groups` claim that is supposedly there.

From what I understood these scopes were needed for this to work:

[image]

Is there a specific option that needs to be enabled as well?

Notes:

- We have configured Congito to use IAM Identity Center SAML application as the external identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this we found out there was a misconfiguration on the client side. It was missing the `OpenID` scope but had the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin`, `email` and `profile` scopes. After adding the `openid` scope the token started including the `cognito:groups` claim.